# No output? C++14

Tags: c++, c++14

So I'm trying to do a challenge called 3n+1, where I have to tell how many times the program has to multiply or divide until n=1 but I don't get any output from the program. Please help?
p.s. I'm using C++ 14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
int d=0;
int main() {
    cin>> n;
    for(int i=n; i<=1;){
        if(n=1){
            cout<< d;
        }
        else if(n%2==0){
            d++;
            n/2;
        }
        else{
            d++;
            n*3+1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't even have a `<<` operator in your code.

Comment: `cout << d`, not `cout >> d`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: change cout>> to cout<<

Comment: you do not change or use i

Comment: try stepping through your code with a debugger

Comment: [Get a book and read it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). There's a ridiculous number of trivial errors in this code.

Comment: If you want to learn the ins and outs of developing on linux (which is where I recommend you start because you won't have to buy any software), take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623040/c-development-on-linux-where-do-i-start

Comment: ok so i fixed the typo, but i still dont get an out put

Comment: Try inputting `0`. It is less than 1, so the loop starts. Then, `n=1` is true because it will set `n`'s value to 1 and evaluates as 1, which means true. As a result, `cout<< d;` will be executed and it will print many `0` in infinity loop without changing the value of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

Possible fix:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n; // you don't need the values to be global
    int d=0;
    cin>> n;
    for(; ;){ // deleted i because it wasn't used
        if(n<=1){ // compare here, don't assign here
            cout<< d;
            break; // exit the loop
        }
        else if(n%2==0){
            d++;
            n=n/2; // please update n here
        }
        else{
            d++;
            n=n*3+1; // also please update n here
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```