# Configuring Opensuse Leap 15.2 for C++ development

Tags: c++, opensuse

How to configure distro OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 for C++ development?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ development on linux - where do I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623040/c-development-on-linux-where-do-i-start)

Comment: this question is a google question. if you want to use stackoverflow, please ask more specific questions and show us what you have tried and what your problem is. Your question is like asking someone to do your homework instead of trying it yourself and ask for support man :D